# ruby datamapper how to include child associations from has n association in query

Tags: ruby, ruby-datamapper

Suppose I have an `Article` with n `Comments`. How would I go about grabbing all the comments with the article in one query with DataMapper?

Something like the following false code:

```
Article.get(:id).include(:comments).to_json
```

I want the associated comments to be returned in the json like so:

```
{
  article object
  comments: [
    { comment object },
    { comment object } 
  ]
}
```

Seems like there must be a better way than grabbing the comments, and manually adding them to an attributes hash before calling to_json.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found it on https://github.com/datamapper/dm-serializer in `lib/to_json.rb`

There are two options it seems, `relationships` and `methods` as options to the `to_json` method. Default inclusions are not yet possible, but requested:

```
@article.to_json(methods: [ :comments ])
```

To go deeper, there is an undocumented (so subject to change) example in a comment in the code is:

```
comments.to_json(:relationships=>{:user=>{:include=>[:first_name],:methods=>[:age]}})
```

So something like:

```
@article.to_json(relationships: { comments: { methods: [ :likes ] } }
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Surprised how difficult this was to find!

Comment: Great ... i have been just looking for this